# Programatically create a new role

Tags: 7, users

I am trying to create a module which will easily allow me to set up basic sites with specific settings on the fly for a project I'm working on. I am having trouble creating a new user role. I have tried the following code within `hook_update_N()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$role = new stdClass(); // create your Class
$role->name = 'editor';
user_role_save($role);
```

How do I programatically create a new role?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$roles = array('role1','role2','role3');
foreach($roles as $name) {
 $existing_role = user_role_load_by_name($name);
 if (empty($existing_role)) {
  $role = new stdClass();
  $role->name = $name;
  user_role_save($role);
 }
}
```

I have placed the same snippet in module install file and it is working just fine. You need to enable and then uninstall the module and re-enable it, I hope it will work.

Comment: I kind of disagree with this approach...  If you're planning on setting up new sites from scratch then you should be making a profile, not a module.  Also someone should point out why `module_update_****()` doesn't work - it's because modules utilise a highwater mark for applying updates.  Generally they're used for database schema changes (which shouldn't be applied more than once), hence a newly installed module won't run any `module_update_****()` as the database schema should already be defined and up-to-date, so no updates are required.